# Twitter : When i used https://github.com/JoeMayo/LinqToTwitter for auth user , i m not getting any webhook

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, linq-to-twitter

I created app on Twitter account @ etechice

```
app name = ice_dev
environment = dev
```

I used https://github.com/twitterdev/account-activity-dashboard  for webhook register and auth user.

whenever I auth user with this app, I m getting all the webhook. (direct message)

But when I auth user with [LinqToTwitter](https://github.com/JoeMayo/LinqToTwitter) 1 in .net with same app credential I m not getting any webhook for the respected user.

in both case webhook endpoint is same.

Please help me out here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved.

Missing one step POST account_activity/all/:env_name/subscriptions

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/subscribe-account-activity/api-reference/aaa-premium#post-account-activity-all-env-name-subscriptions